# ffmpeg .bat script to change frame rate for multiple clips in a folder?

Tags: batch-file, video, ffmpeg

How do I write a .bat file in Windows 10 that changes the frame rate for multiple mp4 video clips in a folder? For example; change the frame rate from 50fps to 25fps (without re-encoding or dropping frames, so that footage is essentially slowed down.)

At the moment these are the commands I've tried using in two separate .bat text files. (I'd like to combine them but don't know how yet).

```
for %%A IN (*.mp4) DO ffmpeg -y -i "%%A" -c copy -f h264 "%%A.h264"

for %%A IN (*.h264) DO ffmpeg -y -r 25 -i "%%A" -c copy
    "%%A_25.mp4"
```

Problem is these commands don't replace the file extension type, they append to the existing one, ie. '.mp4' becomes '.mp4.h264' then '.mp4.h264_25fps.mp4', and I can't get the second one to work for some reason.

Any advice appreciated. How do I replace the existing file extensions for a group of clips and combine commands into a single .bat?

Comment: See `for /?`, the modifier section. `%%~nA` for example is the base name without extension.

Comment: What do you mean "how to combine them"? Just write both lines into the same batch file.

Comment: I tried to combine them with && but didn't seem to work and wasn't sure if that's the right formatting? Do I just write them on separate lines?

Comment: yes, just separate lines.